# Naver jquery plugin don't allow to click the link in the menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, nav

I have a problem with the plugin Naver by formstone, when I set the plugin with my  menu the link inside it don't go to anywhere, they are clickable but only thank to the css rule pointer. I've set up a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kJ3kw/5/).
Thanks guys!

```
.sito{
max-width:960px;
margin:15px auto;
font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;

#menu{
margin-top:8px;
width:10%;
float:right;
text-align:right;}

#tutto{
width:80%;
margin:0 auto;
margin-top:8px;}
```

Answer (score 3):

The links don't go anywhere because that's what you've told it to do:

```
$(".menu a").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Remove those 4 lines from your fiddle and now the links do something.